# Activate submit button on form change and detach event listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling

We have pages that contain 1-3 forms. Each form does have a submit button which is styled as inactive<sup>*</sup> as long as the user didn't change the form.

Now I need to:

- remove the class from the button as soon as the form changes
- remove the event listener from the form

I came up with this:

```
for (const form of Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('form'))) {
    const formHandlerChange = event => {
        const submit = form.getElementsByClassName('disabled')[0];
        submit.classList.remove('disabled');
        form.removeEventListener('change', formHandlerChange);
    };

    form.addEventListener('change', formHandlerChange);
}
```

Is this a good solution? Is it a bad thing to create `formHandlerChange` for each form? Would it be better to get the form each time `formHandlerChange` is entered manually and have this function defined only once outside the loop?

<sub><sup>*</sup> It's also `disabled` but I removed it for simplicity of this review.</sub>

Comment: Is it really necessary to remove the event handler after it triggers? In your case it would seem that you would just remove the `disabled` class more than once.
What I prefer to do, instead of removing the event, is to check some condition. For example:  `if (submit.classlist.contains('disabled') { ...`

Comment: Well, I think that getting the DOM element over and over again only to check whether a class is set already seems like a lot of overhead? However, I could add an extra class to the form like `enabled` and test this for `event.target`, but this only makes the code more complex than needed, right? What do you think? @MarcRohloff

Comment: I think that you're not going to notice a drop in performance for this kind of usage and you can always use Máté's suggestion of using `currentTarget` to avoid the lookup. I really don't think either direction would be wrong and you should do what you think is best. My rule of thumb is mostly just to be consistent across your code-base.

Comment: I also just noticed your asterisk comment. If you are disabling the button then why use a class at all? You can target it in css with the `:disabled` and `:enabled` pseudo-classes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `event.currentTarget` instead of `form`, you can declare the event handler function once and reuse it:

```
function formHandlerChange(event) {
    const form = event.currentTarget;
    const submit = form.querySelector('.disabled');
    submit.classList.remove('disabled');
    form.removeEventListener('change', formHandlerChange);
}

for (const form of document.querySelectorAll('form')) {
    form.addEventListener('change', formHandlerChange);
}
```

(Note: I also used `querySelector()` and `querySelectorAll()` as they are more flexible than the various `getElementBy` methods)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As asked in the OP, could you explain, why this is better than the "original"? Does this have a better performance? Is it easier to understand for other developers reading the code?

Comment: Thanks for `querySelector` - didn't have this in mind. A note: For the code ro tun in Edge unfortunately you need `Array.from()`, see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47287344/edge-15-throws-error-when-using-for-of-on-a-nodelist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47287344/2711071).

Comment: I'd say this is a bit more readable, since it reduces the depth of nested code. Technically you're also saving a little bit of memory by only declaring the function once, but that's negligible. Generally, I just prefer to reuse as much code as I can. Also, I wasn't aware of the Edge bug, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thanks again. Good point here with the level of nesting. Yeah, I only know that Edge quirk, because I asked that question on SO. :D